How do I query geopoint locations in cloud firestore using dart and flutter?
In my cloud firestore, I have a bunch of geopoints. Right now, they don't have any geohashes. Here is how I add the locations:
locations.add({
  'coords' : GeoPoint(position.latitude, position.longitude)
});

They are stored under locations in my database. Now, my question is: if I have a bunch of geopoints in my database, and a location of my choosing, how can I query the database to return all locations that are within x distance away from the location I chose? Is there an inbuilt query (which I assume is the case, otherwise what's the point of a GeoPoint?).
I looked online and read the documentation for Cloud Firestore queries, but nothing came up in the official documentation for Dart: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries

Take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire2

thanks @rstrelba! actually I think geoflutterfire_plus 0.0.32 is better since its more up-to-date after experimenting
